# Mocha, Chai - loop in test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

How should I write unit test for function which should test: `50 < n < 100`? Is there better way than loop in test? Can I pass arguments to test function to generate test case based on that arguments? ex.

```
it('should return $n+1', function(n){
  expect(add(n)).to.be.eql(n+1);
},[ 1, 2, 3])
```

and it should show result as 3 different tests:

```
should return 1+1
should return 2+1
should return 3+1
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/HBJP46lyTbBkH4Pclu2S

Comment: That sounds like wishful thinking if Chai doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/):

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].forEach(value => {
  it(`should return ${ value }+1`, () => {
    expect(add(value)).to.be.eql(value + 1);
  })
});

// The same, but for older versions of Node.js/browser:
[ 1, 2, 3 ].forEach(function(value) {
  it('should return ' + value + '+1', function() {
    expect(add(value)).to.be.eql(value + 1);
  })
});
```

Comment: here is a direct link to a section about this in mocha's documentation : https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests

Comment: This is really error prone when you start to run more than a few lines in the test. For once you will see that errors will often reference wrong line. You should have a test case message in the array, the array should contain expectations not just the value and the message should tell you which failed since chai won't. `expect(expectation, testCaseMessage)`